# CSS radial menu

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-shapes

**What I'd like to do:**

I would like to create a **radial menu** as shown below, considering all elements in the picture interactive, i.e the image in centre as well as the four quarters around it.
It's important that the solution is cross-browser compatible.
This is just a simple example as the parts dont really have to be quarters, they can be any possible number of parts :

[image: CSS radial menu]

**Solutions Tried So Far :**

I have tried using CSS3 round div with border , where the border have these images as background, but doesnt really work well, as each element has to be a stand-alone element.

I heard about css-shapes, but I don't know how to use it to create the radial menu.

**EDIT:**
Maybe there is also a way to add a text caption to each of these images...

Thank you for help!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @linuscl are you trying to make a clip mask ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek no, i'm trying to make a good startpage for my website... I thought I can implent my idea. Didn't know that this is so difficult.

Comment: @linuscl please check my edit , if this what you are trying to achieve we can re-open the question , or else submit new question.

Comment: I changed your file a little bit: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNEbPZ (Dont need extra transformation) Thank you!

Comment: @web-tiki: Your radial menu is great, but there are some issues on smartphones.

Comment: @web-tiki It seems to be an overflow issue on smartphones (tested with Iphone)

Comment: @web-tiki https://www.dropbox.com/s/h58pue7wxab1mas/Bildschirmfoto%20vom%202015-03-27%2019%3A19%3A39.png?dl=0 Not really rounded corners...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I made this pen with a **css radial menu**. The circular menu appears on hover :

Demo : **[CSS radial menu](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/ZYmZoV)**

The radial shape is made with border radius and the overflow property. The hover animation is handled with CSS transition (scale and oapcity).

For a version with menu titles, see this [DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/YPbZBd)

Full Code for the radial menu :

*HTML :*

```
<span><span></span></span>
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#"><div></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div></div></a>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
body{background:#E3DFD2;box-shadow: inset 0 0 20vmin 0 #585247;}
.wrap{
  position:relative;
  width:80vmin; height:80vmin;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:inherit;
  transform:scale(0.2) translatez(0px);
  opacity:0;
  transition:transform .5s, opacity .5s;
}
a{
  position:absolute;
  left:0; top:0;
  width:47.5%; height:47.5%;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform:scale(.5) translateZ(0px);
  background:#585247;
}
a div{
  height:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  opacity:.5;
  transition:opacity .5s;
  border-radius:inherit;
}
a:nth-child(1){
  border-radius:40vmin 0 0 0;
  transform-origin: 110% 110%;
  transition:transform .4s .15s;
}
a:nth-child(1) div{
  background-image:url('https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg');
}
a:nth-child(2){
  border-radius:0 40vmin 0 0;
  left:52.5%;
  transform-origin: -10% 110%;
  transition:transform .4s .2s;
}
a:nth-child(2) div{
  background-image:url('https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6083/6055581292_d94c2d90e3.jpg');
}
a:nth-child(3){
  border-radius:0 0 0 40vmin;
  top:52.5%;
  transform-origin: 110% -10%;
  transition:transform .4s .25s;
}
a:nth-child(3) div{
  background-image:url('https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6092/6227418584_d5883b0948.jpg');
}
a:nth-child(4){
  border-radius:0 0 40vmin 0;
  top:52.5%; left:52.5%;
  transform-origin: -10% -10%;
  transition:transform .4s .3s;
}
a:nth-child(4) div{
  background-image: url('https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7187/6895047173_d4b1a0d798.jpg');
}
a:nth-child(5){
  width:55%;height:55%;
  left:22.5%; top:22.5%;
  border-radius:50vmin;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 5vmin #E3DFD2;
  transform:scale(1);
}
a:nth-child(5) div{
  background-image: url('https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3766/12953056854_b8cdf14f21.jpg');
}
span{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:45vmin;
  width:10vmin; height:10vmin;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:#585247;
  transform:translateZ(0px);
}
span span{
  position:absolute;
  width:60%;height:3px;
  background:#ACA696;
  left:20%; top:50%;
  border-radius:0;
}
span span:after, span span:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:0; top:-1.5vmin;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background:inherit;
}
span span:after{
  top:1.5vmin;
}
span:hover + .wrap, .wrap:hover{
  transform:scale(.8) translateZ(0px);
  opacity:1;
}
span:hover + .wrap a, .wrap:hover a{
  transform:scale(1) translatez(0px);
}
a:hover div{
  opacity:1;
  transform:translatez(0px);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work on Safari: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h58pue7wxab1mas/Bildschirmfoto%20vom%202015-03-27%2019%3A19%3A39.png?dl=0 (I've already said). Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Thank you! But how can I use the opacity effect by hovering?

Comment: It still doesn't work :( Tip: You can also test it on http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: @linuscl I made a minor fix on the menu http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/YPbZBd?editors=110 I tested in on safari with crossbrowsertesting.com and fixed the issue.

Comment: @web-tiki this code does not work in Safari. Although Safari is not the biggest browser inuscl specifically requested it be "cross-browser compatible".

Comment: @web-tiki Thank you web-tiki. Can I add a image discription by hovering?

Comment: @web-tiki Your solution works fine on Safari. Please add it to your answer :) I'd like to display the description in every part and show each on hovering. I've got problems to position the descriptions in the parts of the radial menu. Also I'd like to set the text on a curve in the parts outside. Thank you!

Comment: I'd like to center with text in the image (on a curve).

Comment: @linuscl I updated the answer and made inserted the text in the menu, see here: http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/YPbZBd (please also delete unrelevant comments)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative, less fancy, have to get clever with `img opacity` + `div background-color` to preserve the hover.

```css
/* CSS */
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  background: white;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
}
div:hover > img {
  opacity: .5;
}
.wrap,
.wrap div:first-child{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.wrap div:first-child {
  float: none;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 30px solid white;
}
div div {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 15px solid white;
}
div div:nth-child(2) img {
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
}
div div:nth-child(3) img {
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
}
div div:nth-child(4) img {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
}
div div:nth-child(5) img{
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300&text=Center" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300&text=Top Left" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300&text=Top Right" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300&text=Bottom Left" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300&text=Bottom Right" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution if you only needed 'four quarters', rather than an unknown amount:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 310px;
  width: 310px;
}
.square {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 10px solid white;
}
.wrap div:hover {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.square:nth-child(1) {
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
.square:nth-child(2) {
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
  background: tomato;
}
.square:nth-child(3) {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
  background: darkorange;
}
.square:nth-child(4) {
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this also possible with background-image transistion? (cross-browser compatible) I tried it with CSS but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I got confused by the other examples here so I tried to simplify them and use container divs that I can put anything into, rather than images. Here is the result if it helps anyone.

```css
/* CSS */
* { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #272727;
}

.container {    /* for the container */ 
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vmin;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
} /* Basically just a responsive container that stays at the page's center */



.box { /* Applies to the four corner boxes within container */
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 2.5vmin solid #272727; /* The 4 borders between the boxes */
}


.center { /* The fifth box at the center, we'll turn it into a circle */
    width: 50vmin;
    height: 50vmin;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;

    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 5vmin solid #272727; /* The circular border in the center */

    z-index: 2;

}

.inner { /* The content holding div inside each of the 5 blocks */
    height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: gold;
}

.center .inner {border-radius: 100%;}

.inner:hover {
    background-color: yellow;    
}


/* In case you want all buttons to have rounded corners, try: */
/*.top-left .inner {border-radius: 50vmin 0 0 0;}
.top-right .inner {border-radius: 0 50vmin 0 0;}
.bottom-left .inner {border-radius: 0 0 0 50vmin;}
.bottom-right .inner {border-radius: 0 0 50vmin 0;}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <div class="container">        
        <div class="box top-left"><div class="inner"></div></div>
        <div class="box top-right"><div class="inner"></div></div>
        <div class="box bottom-left"><div class="inner"></div></div>
        <div class="box bottom-right"><div class="inner"></div></div>
        <div class="center"><div class="inner"></div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```